# Why/how does SSH fail to authenticate if the *client* machine has a bogus pubkey?

Tags: macos, ssh

On `clienthost` I have a pub:priv keypair stored as `~/.ssh/foo` and `~/.ssh/foo.pub`, respectively.
On `remotehost` I have the pubkey correctly extant in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` such that I can login using `-i ~/.ssh/foo`.

Login is (of course) not contingent on the existence of `clienthost:~/.ssh/foo.pub`: If I rename `~/.ssh/foo.pub` to `~/.ssh/bar.pub` nothing changes.

But if I change a character in `clienthost:~/.ssh/foo.pub` so that it still looks like a valid pubkey, but no longer corresponds to the privkey, I can't login. Why not?

Why/how does SSH care whether the pubkey complement to the privkey is intact--and why is `${privkey}.pub` the search path?

Comment: .... Let me see if I understand your question correctly. You are asking why a private/public key pair no longer works after you CHANGED the public key (not the filename, but the content of the public key), making the private/private key no longer a match result to each other?

Comment: In regards to the 2nd part of your question why the search path [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30788/does-ssh-key-need-to-be-named-id-rsa) may answer your query.

Comment: Correct: why does SSH care whether a public key exists on the clienthost?

Comment: Did you get any error message? When I tried your experiment (changing content of my id_rsa.pub) - it simply provide an error message of `Key_Load_Public: Invalid Format` but does not prevent me from logging to the remote host.

Comment: My Mac is is `OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8` on OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: Same behavior on `OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`

Comment: I do not get any errors no matter how badly I deform the actual pubkey . . . I haven't tried deforming the `ssh-rsa` nor the `user@host` components.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be confusing, but it makes complete sense. Lets consider the most common use case, when the private key is encrypted and not stored in the `ssh-agent`.

In this use case, the client reads both keys (public and private stored in separate files), but does not need to ask you for the passphrase and does not decrypt the private part unless it knows that the key is accepted by the server.

If you modify the public key to something else what is not accepted by the server, the second step of authentication is not performed. By doing this you break the "pair" which is needed to make it properly work.